# titanium twitter not published

Tags: twitter, oauth, publish, titanium, tweets

I am trying to post a tweet on twitter with my mobile app.
I have authorized my account by logging in on the twitter page linked to my app.

Now when i post it gives a 'Not published' alert.

Does anyone know the reason?

Here is my code:

```
submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var oAuthAdapter = new OAuthAdapter('SECRET KEY', 'KEY', 'HMAC-SHA1');

    // load the access token for the service (if previously saved)
    oAuthAdapter.loadAccessToken('twitter');

    oAuthAdapter.loadAccessToken('twitter');

    oAuthAdapter.send('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json', [['status', 'Test from appcelerator ' + Math.random()]], 'Twitter', 'Published.', 'Not published.');

    if (oAuthAdapter.isAuthorized() == false) {
        // this function will be called as soon as the application is authorized 
        var receivePin = function(){
            // get the access token with the provided pin/oauth_verifier
            oAuthAdapter.getAccessToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token');
            // save the access token
            oAuthAdapter.saveAccessToken('twitter');
        };
        // show the authorization UI and call back the receive PIN function 

        oAuthAdapter.showAuthorizeUI('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?' +
        oAuthAdapter.getRequestToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'), receivePin);
    }
});
```

Comment: hm.. difficult to say. your access token/secret seem to be ok since your error occurs in oauthadapter.send(..).

Comment: you only need to load the access token once i think.. but that's not the point.

Comment: you already know that page: http://ziodave.tumblr.com/post/746024933/titanium-implementation-of-twitter-oauth

Comment: set you debug output ti its most detailed level and see what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved, don't know what went wrong.

Perhaps I still had some caching or so.